# Where is the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I've added the reference to **System.Runtime.Serialization** dll to my project but still can't find the **System.Runtime.Serialization.Json** namespace and hence can't find the **DataContractJsonSerializer** class. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll

Comment: Thanks man. But I thought it was in System.Runtime.Serialization!

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll, System.ServiceModel.dll and System.ServiceModel.Web.dll http://forums.silverlight.net/post/47045.aspx

Comment: This namespace seems even more scattered; this walkthrough states you can get part of the namespace only by installing a specific Nuget package: http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/02/aspnet-mvc-dynamic-json-jquery.html

Comment: @ChrisMoschini that package doesn't seem to exist any more, but it is likely all it contained was some framework dependencies / reference-instructions (no actual dlls), to add the above reference (and some others)

Comment: Looked further into it: most of it was also migrated to Newtonsoft.Json / Json.Net (look for Newtonsoft on Nuget).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running .NET 2.0 ? Its first supported in 3.5 and 4.0 check [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think this library is now deprecated in favour of Json.NET. JsonObject is a JObject and uses Json.NET library.

[Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to update it in your VS, it can be added in the project but not updated