# DataContractJsonSerializer' is not defined in wcf .asmx.vb file

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, wcf

**'DataContractJsonSerializer' is not defined.**

**Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Json** 'giving error in this namespace
This namespace is working on my local host bu not on the server

For this i am using the Newtonsoft.json.dll

Comment: Have you definitely copied over the Newtonsoft.json.dll into your \bin folder on the server?

Comment: yes i have copied this Newtonsoft.json.dll in bin folder of my project

Comment: Does your bin has System.Runtime.Serialization, which gives you the error?

Comment: @kostasch. It's actually in `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll`

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer is part on System.Runtime.Serialization.Json which you have refence System.Runtime.Serialization in your project

Comment: @DaveHogan No,DataContractJsonSerializer is part on System.Runtime.Serialization. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization is working fine in namespace but when i try to add .json behind the serilization it dosnt show that class.Also i have used system.servicemodel.web.dll now for that which namespace should i import

Comment: @kostasch. We're kind of both right - the namespaces were scattered across assemblies (in .NET < 3.5) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.90).aspx `Namespace:  System.Runtime.Serialization.Json`
`Assembly:  System.ServiceModel.Web (in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll)`

Comment: op - can you confirm the .NET version you're running on the server?

Comment: @DaveHogan ehhehe :) yes indeed. Your are right.

Comment: so what you suggest right now which is more helpful for me?

Comment: i am using 4.5 version on server

Answer (score 1):

try by using **System.ServiceModel.Web.dll**

See [Where is the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682147/where-is-the-system-runtime-serialization-json-namespace)

Comment: @ Code Rider, I didn't do much except googling it in this case :)