# How do I include 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json' namespace in my VSCode project on Mac OS X?

Tags: c#, json, macos, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I was hoping to use `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` in a simple Visual Studio Code console app on my Mac OS X but I am running into this compile error:

`The type or namespace name 'Json' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Based on this post - [Where is the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682147/where-is-the-system-runtime-serialization-json-namespace), I added `"System.ServiceModel.Web": "1.0.0"` to my project.json file but that did not help. I added `1.0.0` since that's the only version I found in nuget - https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Web/

As an alternative, I tried using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.8 by adding the following in my project.json - `"Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8"` but then adding the reference of `using Newtonsoft.Json;` again gives a compile error of - `The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Ultimately I would like to derserialize a json stream from my VSCode console app, so hoping to get pointers on how that can be done?

Comment: Using `"Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8"` should have worked...could you share you project.json file?

Comment: Here you go - https://gist.github.com/VegaFromLyra/d3185932187b34126814. Maybe I don't have the dependencies listed in the right place?

Comment: whoops so looks like I did have it in the wrong place, using this version - https://gist.github.com/VegaFromLyra/d4680503f889df153d89 now works with Newtonsoft.Json. But looks like `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` is not supported on VSCode + OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` is not going to get ported to .Net Core; you did the right thing by going to `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Unfortunately, you added it only to the `dnxcore50` section; you need to add it to the framework-agnostic dependency section:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "System.ServiceModel.Web": "1.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8"
  },
  "commands": {
    "run": "run"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
        "System.ServiceModel.Web": "1.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```