# dictionary to json with key names

Tags: c#, json

I have a dictionary `Dictionary<int, string>` of ints and strings, where ints are ids and strings are usernames, and when I convert it to `JSON` using `Json.NET` I get something like the following:

```
{"3":"jack","2":"john"}
```

I convert it like so:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictFriends = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach (var id in resultList)
{
    var user = db.Users.Find(id);
    string friend = user.Username;

    dictFriends.Add(id, friend);
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictFriends);
```

But I am hoping to get something like so:

```
[
{ "id": "3", "user": "jack"},
{ "id": "2", "user": "john"},
]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: how does your `dictFriends` looks like

Comment: In JSON, an object is serialized as a dictionary. If you want the values to be serialized as properties of an object, use a list of objects, *not* a dictionary. Eg, `resultList.Select(new {id=id,user=friend);`

Comment: Which ORM are you using? You could modify your query so it returns just a list of objects with only the ID,Name properties that can be serialized directly. In EF you could change your entire code to `db.Users.Where(u=>resultList.Contains(u=>u.ID)).Select(u=>new {id=u.ID, user=u.UserName});`. The exact same query can be used with LINQ to NH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you'd have to transform the dictionary into something JSON.NET would recognise as being an IEnumerable:

```
// YOUR DICTIONARY
var dictFriends = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    {1,"Jack"},
    {2,"John"},
    {3,"Jeff"}
};

// TRANSFORM INTO IENUMERABLE
var transformed = from key in dictFriends.Keys
                  select new { id = key, user = dictFriends[key] };

// SERIALIZE
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(transformed);
```

Output:

> [
>   {"id":1, "user":"Jack"},
>   {"id":2, "user":"John"},
>   {"id":3, "user":"Jeff"}
>   ]

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a Dictionary as an Array/List, writing to an existing key will overwrite it. Also your current key type is `int` therefore you would have JSON output such as

```
{1: "jack", 2: "john"}
```

Instead set your object type to `List<Dictionary<string, Object>>`

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> friends = new List<Dictionary<string, Object>>();

foreach (var id in resultList)
{
    var user = db.Users.Find(id);
    string friend = user.Username;

    Dictionary<string, object> dictFriend = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    dictFriend.Add("id", id);
    dictFriend.Add("name" , friend);
    friends.Add(dictFriend);
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(friends);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

The below will produce output in the form you're after; only instead of `id` and `user` your fields would be named `key` and `value`.  The reason being those are the property names on the dictionary.

If you needed to change those names also (i.e. it's not just the structure you're interested in), you'd need to override the dictionary with a custom class, where you could add attributes such as `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "User")]` to the properties to change how they're parsed...  See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm for more.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictFriends = new Dictionary<int, string>();

dictFriends.Add(1, "Alice");
dictFriends.Add(2, "Bob");

string jsonString;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    //NB: DataContractJsonSerializer is in assembly System.Runtime.Serialization.dll - and others; http://stackoverflow.com/a/2682197/361842 
    DataContractJsonSerializer dcjs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(dictFriends.GetType());
    dcjs.WriteObject(ms, dictFriends);

    ms.Position = 0;
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms)) {
        jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

Debug.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

Sample output:

```
[{"Key":1,"Value":"Alice"},{"Key":2,"Value":"Bob"}]
```